# Equivalence of matrix norms: $C_1 \cdot \|A\|_p \leq \|A\|_q \leq C_2 \|A\|_p ~~~\forall A \in \mathbb{R}^{m×n}$

Tags: real-analysis, matrices, inequality, normed-spaces

**Using :** $$ \|x\|_p \leq \lambda_{pq}(n) \cdot\|x\|_q \ \ \ \ \ ,\ \   \ \lambda_{pq}(n):= \left\{\begin{matrix}
1, \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ p \geq q
\\ 
n^{(\frac{1}{p} - \frac{1}{q})}, \ \ p \geq q
\end{matrix}\right.$$ 
**and** $$ \|A\|_p := \max_{\|x\|_p = 1} \|Ax\|_p = \max_{x \neq 0} \frac{\|A\|_p}{\|x\|_p} $$

**show that** $\exists \ 0 < C_1 \leq C_2$ **such that :** $$C_1 \cdot \|A\|_p \leq \|A\|_q \leq C_2 \|A\|_p \ \ \ \ \forall A \in \mathbb{R}^{m×n}$$

**What I have done :**

$$\|A\|_p = \max_{x \neq 0} \frac{\|Ax\|_p}{\|x\|_p} \leq \max_{x \neq 0} \frac{\|A\|_p\cdot||x||_p}{\|x\|_p} \leq \max_{x \neq 0} \frac{\|A\|_p}{\|x\|_p}\cdot \lambda_{pq}(n)\cdot\|x\|_q$$

$$\text{if } p<q \text{ then } \leq \max_{x \neq 0} \frac{\|A\|_p}{\|x\|_p}\cdot n^{(\frac{1}{p} - \frac{1}{q})}\cdot\|x\|_q = n^{(\frac{1}{p} - \frac{1}{q})} \cdot \max_{x \neq 0} \frac{\|A\|_p \cdot\|x\|_q}{\|x\|_p} \text{ if } p<q \text{ then } \leq \max_{x \neq 0} \frac{\|A\|_p \cdot\|x\|_q}{\|x\|_p}$$

**So I have** : $$\|A\|_p\leq n^{(\frac{1}{p} - \frac{1}{q})}\cdot \max_{x \neq 0} \frac{\|A\|_p \cdot\|x\|_q}{\|x\|_p}$$ **but I can't manage to have** $$C_1 \cdot \|A\|_p\leq \max_{x \neq 0} \frac{\|Ax\|_q}{\|x\|_q}$$

Comment: You do not need to consider the subcases it can be done globaly. See below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### With OP idea

For $x\in\Bbb R^d$, we have $$\|x\|_p \leq \lambda_{pq}(d) \cdot\|x\|_q \ \ \ \ \ ,\ \   \ \lambda_{pq}(d):= \begin{cases}
1, & p \geq q
\\ 
d^{(\frac{1}{p} - \frac{1}{q})}, & p \geq q
\end{cases} $$

Hence By Symmetry$$\lambda^{-1}_{pq}(d) \cdot\|x\|_q \le \|x\|_p \leq \lambda_{qp}(d) \cdot\|x\|_q \tag{II}$$

Then, for $x\in\Bbb R^n$ we have, $Ax\in \Bbb R^m$ and hence,
$$\|Ax\|_p \overset{(II)}{\le}\lambda_{pq}(m) \cdot\|Ax\|_q \le \lambda_{pq}(m) \|A\|_q\cdot\|x\|_q \overset{(II)}{\le}  \lambda_{pq}(m)\lambda_{qp}(n) \|A\|_q\cdot\|x\|_p$$

that is $$\|A\|_p=\max_{x\neq0}\frac{\|Ax\|_p}{\|x\|_p} \le   \lambda_{pq}(m)\lambda_{qp}(n) \|A\|_q $$

That is $$ \color{blue}{ \|A\|_p \le   \lambda_{pq}(m)\lambda_{qp}(n)\|A\|_q }$$

By symmetry we have,

$$ \color{blue}{ \|A\|_q \le  \lambda_{pq}(n)\lambda_{qp}(m) \|A\|_p }$$

That is

$$ \color{blue}{ \lambda^{-1}_{pq}(n)\lambda^{-1}_{qp}(m) \|A\|_p \le  \|A\|_q \le   \lambda_{pq}(m)\lambda_{qp}(n) \|A\|_p }$$

Comment: How did you went from $\|Ax\|_p \overset{(II)}{\le}\lambda_{pq}(m) \cdot\|Ax\|_q \le \lambda_{pq}(m) \|A\|_q\cdot\|x\|_q \overset{(II)}{\le}  \lambda_{pq}(m)\lambda_{qp}(n) \cdot\|x\|_p$ to $\|A\|_p=\max_{x\neq0}\frac{\|Ax\|_p}{\|x\|_p} \le   \lambda_{pq}(m)\lambda_{qp}(n) \|A\|_q$

Comment: sorry there us the norm of A missing .

Comment: check the edit now . pleases do up vote on up arrow afterward.

Comment: Why there is sometimes $(m)$, $(d)$, $(n)$ ?

Comment: d is the general setting: whenever I want to apply $(II)$ I have to do it with respect to d=n or d=m depending on which vector I am using

Answer (score 0):

> **Answer to the question:** for all $A\in\Bbb R^{m\times n}$ we have, 
>   $$ \color{blue}{n^{-\frac1p}m^{-\frac1q} \|A\|_p \le  \|A\|_q \le  m^{\frac1p}n^{\frac1q} \|A\|_p }$$ See Below for explanatory details.

Hence take $$C_2 =m^{\frac1p}n^{\frac1q}, ~~~~C_{1}^{-1}=n^{\frac1p}m^{\frac1q}$$

> **Lemma:** for all $x\in\Bbb R^d $ We have,
>   $$ \color{red}{d^{-\frac1q} \cdot\|x\|_q\le  \|x\|_p \leq d^{\frac1p} \cdot\|x\|_q\tag{I}}$$
>   **Proof:**
>   Indeed,  for $x\in\Bbb R^d $ we get  $$\|x\|_\infty \le \|x\|_p\le  n^{\frac1p}\|x\|_\infty \quad\text{and}\quad\|x\|_\infty \le \|x\|_q\le  n^{\frac1q}\|x\|_\infty $$
>   Then we have, $$ \color{red}{d^{-\frac1q} \cdot\|x\|_q\le  \|x\|_p \leq d^{\frac1p} \cdot\|x\|_q\tag{I}}$$

Then, for $x\in\Bbb R^n$ we have, $Ax\in \Bbb R^m$ and hence,
$$\|Ax\|_p \overset{(I)}{\le} n^{\frac1p} \cdot\|Ax\|_q \le  m^{\frac1p} \|A\|_q\cdot\|x\|_q \overset{(I)}{\le}  m^{\frac1p}n^{\frac1q}  \cdot\|x\|_p$$

that is $$\|A\|_p=\max_{x\neq0}\frac{\|Ax\|_p}{\|x\|_p} \le  m^{\frac1p}n^{\frac1q} \|A\|_q $$

That is $$ \color{blue}{ \|A\|_p \le  m^{\frac1p}n^{\frac1q} \|A\|_q }$$

By symmetry we have,

$$ \color{blue}{ \|A\|_q \le  n^{\frac1p}m^{\frac1q} \|A\|_p }$$

That is

$$ \color{blue}{n^{-\frac1p}m^{-\frac1q} \|A\|_p \le  \|A\|_q \le  m^{\frac1p}n^{\frac1q} \|A\|_p }$$

Hence take $$C_2 =m^{\frac1p}n^{\frac1q}, ~~~~C_{1}^{-1}=n^{\frac1p}m^{\frac1q}$$

Comment: How have you done $\max_{x\neq0}\frac{\|Ax\|_p}{\|x\|_p} \le  m^{\frac1p}n^{\frac1q} \|A\|_q$ ? Because $\|Ax\|_p \le m^{\frac1p}n^{\frac1q}  \cdot\|x\|_p$ so $\max_{x\neq0}\frac{\|Ax\|_p}{\|x\|_p}$ becomes $\leq \max_{x \neq 0} \frac{m^{\frac1p}n^{\frac1q}{\|x\|_p}} \cdot \|x\|_p} = \frac{m^{\frac1p}n^{\frac1q}$

Comment: Please I cannot read what you wrote. send again

Comment: I guees your question check the check this above $$\|Ax\|_p \overset{(I)}{\le} n^{\frac1p} \cdot\|Ax\|_q \le  m^{\frac1p} \|A\|_q\cdot\|x\|_q \overset{(I)}{\le}  m^{\frac1p}n^{\frac1q}  \cdot\|x\|_p$$

Comment: Ok thanks but you didn't use $||x||_p \leq \lambda_{pq}(n) \cdot||x||_q \ \ \ \ \ ,\ \   \ \lambda_{pq}(n):= \left\{\begin{matrix}
1, \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ p \geq q
\\ 
n^{(\frac{1}{p} - \frac{1}{q})}, \ \ p \geq q
\end{matrix}\right.$ ..

Comment: That one is the one sided constant: So I did not fine it so relevant:)

Comment: Don't for get to upvote:)